# Find Unique Values in a Pandas Dataframe Cell

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, unique

**Sample DF**

```
data = {'name': ['Jason , Jason', 'Molly', 'Tina', 'Jake', 'Amy'], 
        'year': ['2012 , 2012 , 2016 , 2016', 2012, 2013, 2014, 2014], 
        'reports': ['4 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 6 , 7', 24, 31, 2, 3]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, index = ['Cochice', 'Pima', 'Santa Cruz', 'Maricopa', 'Yuma'])
```

**Looks like**:

```
                     name            ...                                   year
Cochice     Jason , Jason            ...              2012 , 2012 , 2016 , 2016
Pima                Molly            ...                                   2012
Santa Cruz           Tina            ...                                   2013
Maricopa             Jake            ...                                   2014
Yuma                  Amy            ...                                   2014
```

I want unique value on every cell of `Cochice` index. I tried `drop_duplicates` and `nunique` but none of them is working.

In my original df the number of columns can be more than 3

**Output Df**

```
             name  reports       year
Cochice     Jason  4,5,6,7  2012,2016
Pima        Molly       24       2012
Santa Cruz   Tina       31       2013
Maricopa     Jake        2       2014
Yuma          Amy        3       2014
```

Comment: Does your real data have a space before the comma (like in your "Jason ,Jason" entry) or is that just a typo here?

Comment: Actually I have space in  all the values..let me update the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not aware of any built-in Pandas function which can do this, so have come up with a solution using `applymap` and a custom function which splits on commas, strips whitespace, and joins back together the unique elements into a single string. It's not pretty and likely not terribly efficient, but it should work:

```
In [15]: df1.applymap(lambda x: x if ',' not in str(x) else ','.join(sorted(set(y.strip() for y in(x.split(','))))))
Out[15]: 
             name  reports       year
Cochice     Jason  4,5,6,7  2012,2016
Pima        Molly       24       2012
Santa Cruz   Tina       31       2013
Maricopa     Jake        2       2014
Yuma          Amy        3       2014
```

Edit to show applying to only a certain index rather than all rows:

```
df1.loc[['Cochice']].applymap(lambda x: x if ',' not in str(x) else ','.join(sorted(set(y.strip() for y in(x.split(','))))))
Out[24]: 
          name  reports       year
Cochice  Jason  4,5,6,7  2012,2016
```

Comment: This worked..just  1 more query..can this be applied specifically to a particular "Index" value and not the whole df. In above case `Cochice`

Comment: @Curious_Mind Thanks!